# Is it bad to use session.cookie_lifetime for keeping session upon closed browser window?

Tags: php, session

I'm experimenting with PHP and I noticed that if you use SESSIONS, they expire when you close the browser window.

I searched in here and they said you can use `session.cookie_lifetime` but it's not recommended to have it on for too long. My question is. Sites like this for example, or reddit, or facebook. They have a "remember me" button so the session is not closed when you close the browser. How do they achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a session is to be closed when you close the browser.  If you don't want that behavior, you should use cookies rather than a session.  Look at the [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function in PHP.  This will allow you to create a cookie that will last a long time (even years), and is ideal for long-lasting persistent data, like a "Remember Me?" function.

Comment: But, I've also read that if I store the info of an user in a cookie, since cookies as stored in the browser, a hacker could change the cookie. So for example, right now when I log in a user, that user id is stored in the `$_SESSION['userId']` variable. But if I do that with cookies, then the hacker can change the id and login as any other user. Of cours I'm missing something here, but I don't know what is it.

Comment: You don't want to store sensitive data like this that can be modified by someone into something predictable. Instead, you can use a token. So you could create a randomized token for the user, then store the token. If someone hacks the user's computer and modifies the cookie, it's not something predictable like a User ID. Instead, it's a token that a hacker would have no way of predicting. Then if the hacker changed it, the worst that would happen is that the user wouldn't get logged in, but they wouldn't be able to change it to something that matches another user.